# Is there an equivalent of :hover in react-native-web?

Tags: css, react-native, expo, react-native-web, metro-bundler

I'm trying to make a react-native app using expo, since expo and metro bundler are compatible with react-native-web, I get my web view and Android/IOS with almost the same code.
How can I do something like the equivalent of css :hover in there?
Since there's no css and styles are done in Javascript objects like this and later converted to html css elements?
Is there a built-in functionality for this or do I need to use a library?

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  element: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    margin: 20,
  }
})
```

Comment: https://www.reactnative.guide/8-styling/8.0-intro.html - "Hence, you do not have access to pseudo-classes like :hover, :active, etc."

Comment: You cannot really hover on mobile hence why there is no option.  I'm sure there is a round away way to do it but it's not logical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

react-native-web supports hover based events in a `Pressable` via the `onHoverIn` and `onHoverOut` props. You can find an example in their docs:
https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/pressable/

Comment: Thank you so much ! @Kipnoedels
That worked :)

**
<Pressable onHoverIn={handleHover}>
    <Text>Hoverable</Text>
</Pressable>
**